# How to set an enterprise keyword field with javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, enterprise-keywords

How could I set/change the value of an enterprise keyword field in a form using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The Enterprise Keyword works pretty similar to the Managed Metadata Field...
So i was able to set the values as i did with the Managed Metadata Field (using javascript):

```
    var myMetadataField = $('div[Title="' + MetadataField + '"]').find('div[role="textbox"]');
    myMetadataField.text("");

    var myMetadataField = $('div[Title="' + MetadataField + '"]').find('div[role="textbox"]');
    var myContainer = myMetadataField.parent().parent().parent();
    var divElement = myContainer.get(0);
    myMetadataField.text(listData.join(";"));

    var controlObject = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ControlObject(divElement);
    controlObject.validateAll();
```

Where MetadataField is the title of your managed Metadata field